# How to cut the desired signal?

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

I need your guidance on how I can **cut the signal** and keep my desired part of the signal only. I have a **physiological signal**. I just want to keep the part of the signal when it goes up (1.5 sec) and stop around 2.5 sec. And remove the beginning and the end of the signal. I am attaching the signal image and the code used to generate it. Could you please guide me on how to do this or is there any Matlab code to do? Looking forward to hearing from you. Thanks
[image]

```
cd 'D:\Research\TFR classification\DATI'
filenames=dir('*.txt');
Fs=500;
TextSize=24;
time_FIF=zeros(1,length(filenames));
for i= 24 %length(filenames)
%% Signal
%close all

fprintf(['\n\n\n *******************************************\n\n'...
    '         CODICE data set = ' filenames(i).name(1:end-4) '\n\n'...
    '         We are  assuming a sampling rate of 500 Hz\n\n'...
    ' *******************************************\n\n'])
%% Import data from text file
opts = delimitedTextImportOptions("NumVariables", 25);
% Specify range and delimiter
opts.DataLines = [1, Inf];
opts.Delimiter = "\t";
% Specify column names and types
opts.VariableNames = ["Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "Var4", "Var5", "Var6", "Var7", "Var8", 
"Var9", "Var10", "Var11", "Var12", "Var13", "Var14", "Var15", "Var16", "Var17", "Var18", 
"Var19", "Var20", "Var21", "Var22", "Var23", "VarName24", "Var25"];
opts.SelectedVariableNames = "VarName24";
opts.VariableTypes = ["string", "string", "string", "string", "string", "string", 
"string", "string", "string", "string", "string", "string", "string", "string", 
"string", "string", "string", "string", "string", "string", "string", "string", 
"string", "double", "string"];
% Specify file level properties
opts.ExtraColumnsRule = "ignore";
opts.EmptyLineRule = "read";
% Specify variable properties
opts = setvaropts(opts, ["Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "Var4", "Var5", "Var6", "Var7", "Var8", 
"Var9", "Var10", "Var11", "Var12", "Var13", "Var14", "Var15", "Var16", "Var17", "Var18", 
"Var19", "Var20", "Var21", "Var22", "Var23", "Var25"], "WhitespaceRule", "preserve");
opts = setvaropts(opts, ["Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "Var4", "Var5", "Var6", "Var7", "Var8", 
"Var9", "Var10", "Var11", "Var12", "Var13", "Var14", "Var15", "Var16", "Var17", "Var18", 
"Var19", "Var20", "Var21", "Var22", "Var23", "Var25"], "EmptyFieldRule", "auto");
opts = setvaropts(opts, "VarName24", "DecimalSeparator", ",");
% Import the data
s = readtable(filenames(i).name, opts);
s = table2array(s);
s = s(1420:3358);
%s = s(4.1*Fs:7.4*Fs);
%% Clear temporary variables
clear opts
%%    
Fig=figure;
plot((1:length(s))/Fs,s,'k')
xlabel('time (s)')
title(['Signal ' filenames(i).name(1:end-4)])
set(gca,'fontsize', TextSize);
set(Fig,'Units', 'Normalized', 'OuterPosition', [0 0 1 1]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have plotted

```
x=(1:length(s))/Fs;
plot((1:length(s))/Fs,s,'k');
```

So you can use something like this to filter between 1.5 and 2.5 secs

```
idx = (x>=1.5) & (x<=2.5);
x_cut = x(idx);
s_cut = s(idx);
```

Comment: Thank you, so than for plot just simply use plot(x_cut, s_cut);.Just in addition to this, if we want to cut in a verticle direction like from 220 and end at 340. Then how can do this?

Comment: You would do exactly the same, but create `idx` based on `s` instead of `x`. Note that cutting based on `y` might mean you concatenate regions which are not continuous, i.e. if there were two bumps you would cut out the middle bit

Comment: I really appreciated it, I got your point. one last query, if you can look at the code, I added just now? now I want to give the out signal (after cutting) as input in the next step. What can we do? looking for kind guidance. thanks

Comment: That's scope creep, please don't change the intent of a question when it has an accepted answer - it can be confusing for future readers. If you have a new question then ask a new question :)

Comment: alright, thank you. will ask another one.